# How to setup signal/slot connection between thread and child thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a class `ParentThread` deriving from `QThread` with the following `run()` method that roughly looks as follows:

```cpp
void ParentThread::run()
{
  QThread *childThread = new QThread;
  QObject::connect(childThread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onChildThreadFinished());
  QObject::connect(childThread, SIGNAL(finished()), childThread, SLOT(deleteLater());
  childThread->start();

  exec();
}
```

The slot `onChildThreadFinished()` is defined on `ParentThread`, and should run in the context of `ParentThread`. However, using the code above, `onChildThreadFinished` only gets called in case the signal/slot connection is a `Qt::DirectConnection`, but then runs in the context of the child thread. In case the signal/slot connection is defined as a `Qt::QueuedConnection`, the slot never gets called. I am using Qt 4.8.5. Any idea what the issue is here?

Comment: Maybe that's because when `finished` is emitted, first `deleteLater` is called which is a direct connection and the `childThread` object gets deleted when the control returns to the event loop. So `onChildThreadFinished` does not get called when the emitter object is destroyed.

Comment: Show how do you create a ParentThread object and its constructor.

Comment: `The slot onChildThreadFinished() is defined on ParentThread, and should run in the context of ParentThread`. Wrong. This is one of the reasons why subclassing `QThread` is discouraged. [*It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run(). This means that all of QThread's queued slots will execute in the old thread.*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#details)

Comment: @Nejat, actually, I added the `deleteLater` slot connection here for correctness sake, in my original code, it is not present.

Comment: @thuga, thanks, that is indeed the whole reason this does not work. You can add your comment as an answer and I'll gladly accept it as the correct answer. I agree that usually you do not want to subclass `QThread` directly. In this case though initially it seemed subclassing made more sense. I am going to rethink my approach now.

Comment: @Nejat Slots connected to signals with `Qt::QueuedConnection` will get executed even if the emitter is destroyed before the slot is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that *The slot onChildThreadFinished() is defined on ParentThread, and should run in the context of ParentThread*. This assumption is wrong. This is one of the reasons why subclassing `QThread` is discouraged.

If you want to use slots in your threads, subclassing `QThread` is not what you want to do. Use worker-object method instead. Subclass `QObject` and call [`QObject::moveToThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) to move your object to a new thread.

Here is what Qt docs say about this:

[*It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run(). This means that all of QThread's queued slots will execute in the old thread. Thus, a developer who wishes to invoke slots in the new thread must use the worker-object approach; new slots should not be implemented directly into a subclassed QThread.*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#details)